# custom code snippet for try-catch Logger in Netbeans

Tags: java, logging, netbeans

Every time I use the bulb hint for adding try-catch blocks in Netbeans, it automatically adds these lines:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger

...
catch(...) {
   Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I found it sort of annoying, because it also adds the necessary imports and since I'm using different logger (slf4j), I'm forced to overwrite it all the time.

Is there a way of customizing that code snippet?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Netbeans, go to menu option Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Hints (Tab) -> Make Sure Language Java is selected -> in the tree select "Error Fixes" - "Surround with try-catch".

And in that screen, to the right, disable the checkbox: "Use java.util.logging.Logger"

Hopefully the below screenshot makes it easier to understand these steps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is really helpful! Finally I don't have to deal with imports anymore while overwriting the catch block.
It would be very nice if one can add a custom snippet, though. Is it even possible?

Comment: @PoloShock AFAIK, I highly doubt if this is possible to have custom snippet for Try-Catch block. You can try if [Custom Code Template](http://jayskills.com/blog/2013/02/03/custom-code-templates-with-netbeans/) works for you. P.S: If you think this answer helped you, please accept it.