# Enclose statement in a try catch block; difference between eclipse and netbean

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, try-catch

Why when I am trying to enclose a statement in a try catch block, eclipse auto generate

```
ex.printStackTrace();
```

where as netbean auto generate

```
Logger.getLogger(Processor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

what is the difference between these two statements?

Comment: They're different IDEs, and they implement different default `Exception` handling routines. Try them and see.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch!!

Answer (score 1):

At least in eclipse, but presumably also in netbeans, you can configure the default content of your catch block. They are just configured differently.

Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates, look for 'Catch block body'

For netbeans check the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467471/custom-code-snippet-for-try-catch-logger-in-netbeans)